# Converting a very simple htaccess into a PHP router?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm hoping I can get some help with a relatively simple problem:

I've been programming a PHP application for university and thanks to a complete lack of forethought by me, the servers they are testing our apps on aren't Apache, they are just the `php -S` servers (PHP built-in server).

So my app relies completely on routing of URIs to one specific file, something I had working well in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.1.0.php [L,QSA]
```

I am aware that you can use router files when using the normal PHP servers, but could anyone help me 'convert' this `.htaccess` file into a PHP router?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

**EDIT:** I guess a better way of putting this question would be, can anyone help me understand what the `.htaccess` file is doing? And then I could convert it into PHP fairly easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy. Use this way `router.php`:

```
<?php
    $path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if (!file_exists($path))
      include "api.1.0.php";
    else
      return false;
?>
```

The above code is a replacement of the `.htaccess` file you have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.1.0.php [L,QSA]
```

> *I guess a better way of putting this question would be, can anyone help me understand what the `.htaccess` file is doing?*

1. **`RewriteEngine On`** - Start the Apache2 Rewrite Engine module.
2. **`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`** - When the file doesn't exist on the path,
3. **`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`** - When the directory doesn't exist on the path,
4. **`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.1.0.php [L,QSA]`** - Whatever you give, serve it to the `api.1.0.php` with the query string, and stop the rewrite rule here.

This code works for this way:

```
php -S localhost:80 router.php
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! You've definitely pointed me on the right track. Would you mind explaining the first line of code in relation to the htaccess (the parse_url)?

Comment: @Ollie Yes definitely. The first line gets the request URL from from the browser, as how you see in the browser's address bar, leaving the domain. It is the `PATH` that was requested.

Comment: @Ollie So, when you give a URL like `http://localhost/users/123/ollie/posts/5`, the `$path` will contain `/users/123/ollie/posts/5`. :)

Comment: @Ollie Did the explanation clarify you?

Comment: @Ollie For understanding what the `.htaccess` is doing, take a look at here: **1. `RewriteEngine On`** - Start the Apache2 Rewrite Engine module.
**2. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`** - When the file doesn't exist on the path,
**3. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`** - When the directory doesn't exist on the path,
**4. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.1.0.php [L,QSA]`** - Whatever you give, serve it to the `api.1.0.php` with the query string, and stop the rewrite rule here.

Comment: Yes! Very clear and concise explanation in my time of need, thank you :^)

Comment: @Ollie See the above comment.