# Remove ?id= in php using .htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove `?id=` from the URL and replace `?id=` with a slash (`/`).

I want to show the address:

```
http://localhost/new/view-seller?id=534f5ddbdd
```

As:

```
http://localhost/new/view-seller/534f5ddbdd
```

I have managed to delete the `.php` from the URL, but I have still issues with `?id=`

The original link with `?id=` accessible. When I navigate to the page without `?id=` I get: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htaccess rewrite GET variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

Comment: If I were you, I'd send _all_ requests that don't exist to a single router script and perform your logic in PHP. The original URL can then be accessed in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36675646/231316). This allows you to write all of your logic, including tests, in PHP, without tweaking htaccess whenever something changes. This is how most frameworks work these days, too.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like the following instead in the *root* `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\da-z]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

The above will rewrite `/<file>/<id>` to `/<file>.php?id=<id>`, providing `/<file>.php` exists. `<file>` can consist of multiple path segments (eg. `new/view-seller` in your example).

This assumes `<id>` is alphanumeric lowercase only. If this is hexadecimal then the regex should be made more specific accordingly.

And, if this should only apply to `view-seller` then the regex should again be made more specific.

---

If you need to combine this with a generic "append `.php`" rule then the above rule should go first. For example:

```
# 1. Rewrite "/<file>/<id>" to "/<file>.php?id=<id>"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([\da-z]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]

# 2. Rewrite "/<file>" to "/<file>.php"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

Rule #2 is bascially the same as your original rule, except your original rule has several issues. (Minor point, but the directory check is redundant here.)